# Animate causing the Frontend to hang in 12.3

Tags: bugs, front-end, animation, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 12.3 and fixed in 12.3.1**

---

Can somebody replicate the following issue with release 12.3.0 or is it only on my machine?

Prerequisite: make sure your Internet connection is working, you are signed in to Wolfram Cloud Account with Mathematica on start up and that the Suggestion bar is enabled.

1.) Start a new Mathematica session and open a new notebook.

2.) Evaluate the following:

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, umax},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {umax, 0.1, 2 Pi}]
```

After a while the Frontend hangs and a popup "The kernel is not responding to a dynamic evaluation" shows up. Also try to click on the slider.

I can replicate the issue on each restart of MMA and I am running macOS 11.3.1. MMA 12.2.0 works perfectly fine.

**Update:**
Adding the Bug tag. The problem is in the Link Paclet "CloudObject" which got some major changes in 12.3.0. If I replace it with the version from 12.2.0 it works again.

Comment: Works fine on my machine using Windows 10, x86, 64-bit. Can you quit, restart your kernel and try again?

Comment: Thank you for trying. I am on MacOS and can replicate the issue each time I restart MMA. Really strange, ...

Comment: Does the problem disappear once you disable the suggestion bar?

Comment: @CA Trevillian: it disappears if I either disable the suggestion bar, minimize the suggestion bar, log out of wolfram cloud account, disable Internet access for Mathematica or if the Internet connection is very very slow. I tracked down the issue pretty far. It seems there is a lock happening in the Frontend when suggestion bar tries to update itself on first execution and is calling some Wolfram Cloud connect function (-> Link Snooper). It only happens on 12.3. 12.2 was fine, so I am pretty sure it is some kind of bug. Calling CloudConnect; before Animate ... also helps.

Comment: Such things happen sometimes if the Animate content is much too heavy. If so, a good workaround would be to first create a list of images like `lst=Table[ParametricPlot[{Sin[12 u] Cos[u], Sin[12 u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, umax}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {umax, 0.1, 2 Pi, eps}]` and choose eps small enough by trial and error. And then to apply `ListAnimate[lst]`. Important to make it in another cell. In this case, the first step can take considerable time to build the list, but you do it prior to demonstrate the animation. However, the animation itself should run fast.

Comment: @Alexei: it actually works if the Suggestion Bar has been loaded before by some other Function or if I either disable Internet connection for MMA, log out of Wolfram Cloud account, evaluate CloudConnect before, minimize or turn off the suggestion bar. The point is that it worked in 12.2.0 and now in 12.3.0 I need these kind of workarounds. Can you replicate the issue? It is important to exactly follow the steps above in a new notebook, where nothing else has been evaluated before.

Comment: It may sound like a silly suggestion, but why not just disable the suggestion bar?

Comment: That's what I did anyway :). I still think this is some bug in 12.3.0 but it only seems to be replicatable on my machine.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Mac OS 11.2.2 (20D80). Start Mathematica 12.3, Click "New document" on the splash screen, Paste code, Evaluate.

Comment: **Can** replicate if I include another step you didn't mention: click on the `umax` slider. (12.3, MacOS 10.15.7)

Comment: (however, bug goes away if I: restart the kernel; delete the output cell; enable dynamic updating; then re-evaluate the expression, in the same mathematica session. If I don't delete the output cell, it hangs. I haven't touched or disabled the suggestion bar.)

Comment: have you [reported the bug](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)? feel free to include my 'testimony' if you haven't yet. :)

Comment: actually, it hangs if I wait long enough anyway, so you can disregard the "click on the `umax` slider" step. I also didn't transcribe my "fix" correctly. the actual process that makes it go away is: restart local kernel from menu; re-evaluate expression; delete "gray box" output; re-enable dynamic evaluation; re-evaluate expression. anything else seems to cause another hang.

Comment: @thorimur: thanks for replicating! Restarting kernel, deleting cell, .. works. Actually evaluating CloudConnect; before Animate also works. I have reported the issue during prerelease testing but unfortunately nobody at WRI could replicate it. Thats why I posted this question. Good to know that I am not the only one. 12.2 works on the same machine.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: are you logged in to your Wolfram Cloud Account and did you turn on the suggestion bar? Is the animation running or getting stuck? Did you try to move the slider?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issues in 12.3 (Mac OS) with Manipulate (as well as Animate). It seems to crash the kernel as soon as I try to move the slider. Disabling the suggestion bar "fixes" the problem.